# PHP7 Error handling issues

Tags: php, error-handling

Recently upgraded php from 5.4 to 7.0

Error handler stopped working.. Tried set_exception_handler() same result.
Does someone faced with this problem?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
set_error_handler('errorHandler');

function errorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {

    switch ($errno) {
        case E_NOTICE:
        case E_USER_NOTICE:
        case E_DEPRECATED:
        case E_USER_DEPRECATED:
        case E_STRICT:
            echo("STRICT error $errstr at $errfile:$errline n");
            break;

        case E_WARNING:
        case E_USER_WARNING:
            echo("WARNING error $errstr at $errfile:$errline n");
            break;

        case E_ERROR:
        case E_USER_ERROR:
        case E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR:
            exit("FATAL error $errstr at $errfile:$errline n");

        default:
            exit("Unknown error at $errfile:$errline n");
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean *stopped working*? This looks like it works the same going back to PHP 5.3: https://3v4l.org/EWuvl

Comment: Warning: set_error_handler() expects the argument (errorHandler) to be a valid callback

Comment: Is your code inside a namespace?

Comment: yes, my code inside a namespace.

Comment: Well that would explain the error - you need to provide the namespace prefix in the call to `set_error_handler`. But you would have seen the same error in PHP 5.4 as well, so I'm not sure why you're only seeing it now you've upgraded.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks!